# Property in vb class file not working

Tags: vb.net

I have a class file "user.vb" that has many properties in it. I have added a new boolean property.

```
Property ViewState() As Boolean
        Get
            Return boolViewState
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            boolViewState = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

It's pretty straight forward, and is the same as other properties in the file, like this one.

```
Property Zip() As String
    Get
        Return strZip
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strZip = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem is, my masterpage can access `user.Zip` with no trouble, but `user.ViewState` doesn't show up in Intellisense and running the page gives me an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What gives?

**Edit**

MasterPage code:

```
HtmlMeta view = new HtmlMeta();
view.Name = "viewport";
if(user.ViewState = false)
{
    view.Content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1";
}
else
{
    view.Content = "width=1040px, initial-scale=1";
}
MetaPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(view);
```

All the other properties of user.vb can be accessed but user.ViewState is not in the intellisense pop-up menu, as if I haven't declared it properly.

Comment: Not enough information. Show us your page code, where it fails.

Comment: Are you sure that the C# web project is referencing a build of the VB library that includes that property?

Comment: Where does your `user` variable come from?

Comment: Declared at the top of the page. `Public User user;`

It works for about 30 other properties, it's just this new one giving me grief.

Comment: Are you sure that the User class doesnot inherit any ASP.Net Control? BCoz, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx shows that every control has a ViewState Property that is not Browsable. Try renaming your the property with ViewState1 or [ViewState]

Comment: @AnshumanChatterjee Thanks for pointing that out, I've renamed it to ViewChange but still have the same problem.

Comment: @ChrisHinton Try a Clean-Rebuild of both the vb.net & c#asp.net projects. If you have added a dll reference of the vb.net project, try removing and readding it.

Comment: I haven't added any new references, I've just added a single property to an existing class file.

Comment: @ChrisHinton Ok. But you have added the property in an VB Project, and accessing it in a C# Project. So your C# Project must be referencing the VB Project(Project Reference or Dll Reference). Therefore, we suspect that the VB Project hasnt been build properly, or the C# Project is not referring the latest dll of the VB Project.

Comment: The C# files are the 2 master pages of an asp website. All the child pages of the same site use the User.vb class for customer information. The master page already references the User.vb file and utilitises some of the properties for existing functions. The only new code in the last two weeks is my new boolean property. I'm not sure how that would break the existing setup though?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information in regards to how you're writing your program. So I'm going to try and give you as many solutions as I can.

First, *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* may have something to do with lack of instantialization "Public User user" must be a "Public User user = new User".

Secondly, the fact that you're not getting access to the Property you added may be due to not having built it after editing. You must save those changes in the vb .DLL file before they are noticeable and usable in the file you want to use it.

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The User.vb file is in the App_Code folder of the project and is currently referenced by roughly 30 pages on the site. Previous changes to the class have been usable right away in any page (including the C# Masterpage). In fact, I can type user.Zip and user.ViewChange in the same line and Zip will work while ViewChange will error.